# Valence First and Last Login of a student in Course

Tags: desire2learn, valence

Is there a way to get the first Login date and last login date of a student in a course using Valence API's?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

No, the Valence Learning Framework APIs do not offer functionality around this sort of reporting data. If you would like to request this functionality, clients of D2L can post suggestions to the Product Ideas Exchange. (https://community.desire2learn.com/d2l/lp/navbars/1796/customlinks/external/15394)